# Generating a .vcf file from Phone Book Contact

Tags: android

How to generate a .vcf file from PhoneBook contacts programmatically in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://code.google.com/p/android-vcard/

It says on the wiki page that it has been taken from android sources, but that the actual sdk doesn't include this library for some reason.